# Adding Advanced Custom Fields to Related Posts in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add a custom field value to related posts functionality, but am currently totally stuck at this:

```
<div class="relatedposts">  
<h3>Related posts</h3>  
<?php  
$orig_post = $post;  
global $post;  
$tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);  

if ($tags) {  
$tag_ids = array();  
foreach($tags as $individual_tag) $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;  
$args=array(  
'tag__in' => $tag_ids,  
'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),  
'posts_per_page'=>4, // Number of related posts to display.  
'caller_get_posts'=>1  
);  

$my_query = new wp_query( $args );  

while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {  
$my_query->the_post();

?>  

<div class="relatedthumb">  
<a rel="external" href="<? the_permalink()?>">
<?php 
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_field('image'), 'full');
print_r( $image[0] ); ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" />
</a>  
</div>  

<? }  
}  
$post = $orig_post;  
wp_reset_query();  
?>  
</div>
```

This mostly works as it is code found online, it is just where to put the reference to the custom field that I seem to be missing. I am unable to place the variable and print_r of this anywhere to see the results.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand. Are you trying to filter the related posts by a tag?

Comment: @CalEvans - Yes, related posts by tag, then get the associated custom field.

Comment: Are you asking about Advanced Custom Fields (the plugin) or advanced custom fields (implementation)?

Comment: @ojrask - Sorry, yes. I want to know how to use the ACF plugin with this.

Answer (score 0):

foreach($tags as $individual_tag) {
        $meta_values = get_post_meta($post->ID,'');

```
    if (in_array('VALUE SEARCHING FOR',$meta_values) {
        $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;
    } // if
} // foreach
```

Fill in the appropriate blanks and this should filter your tags properly.

HTH,

=C=

Comment: Thanks, but it is the ACF image field associated with the post that I am trying to get to work, the filtering of tags works; I get a hyperlink in the output, but not an image.

Answer (score 0):

With ACF, you can pass a post ID to the `get_field` and `the_field` functions:

```
$image_id = get_field( 'image', $post -> ID );
```

If you use the functions without a set post ID, the functions may return the field value of some other globally initialized post.

So your attachment image getter (inside the related posts `WP_Query` loop) would be something like

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_field('image', get_the_ID()), 'full');
```

Make sure your ACF field type is set to image and the wanted variant of it: ID, image object, or image URL. `get_field` will then return either the image's attachment ID, the image object or the image URL.

In your code example, returning an ID would be the correct choice, assuming `wp_get_attachment_image_src` expects an attachment ID.

EDIT:

I just realized, that the ACF image field may not be saving the images to the WP attachment system in a normal way WP does. Try returning the image as an object and `var_dump` the object's contents to see where the `full` size image URL resides there.

I could be wrong and the `wp_get_attachment_image_src` might work fine as is.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Neither approach seem to access the post image in the ACF field.

Comment: What does `var_dump` output for `get_field( 'image', get_the_ID() )`?

Comment: And you're certain there exists a field named `image` and that there is an image or something saved in it for the post being output?

Comment: From what I can see, yes. It is called 'hero_image', so this should output something: while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
  $my_query->the_post();
  $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_field('hero_image', get_the_ID()), 'full');
  var_dump($image);
 ?>

Comment: Yes, in that case `get_field( 'hero_image', $id );` would get the value correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, anyone who may find this useful, I have a solution for getting the ACF field to appear:

```
        <div class="related grid clear">
            <h2>Related posts</h2>
            <?php
            $orig_post = $post;
            global $post;
            $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);

            if ($tags) {
                $tag_ids = array();
                foreach($tags as $individual_tag) $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;
                $args=array(
                    'tag__in' => $tag_ids,
                    'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
                    'posts_per_page'=>9,
                    'caller_get_posts'=>1
                );

                $my_query = new wp_query( $args );

                if($my_query->have_posts()) {
                    while($my_query->have_posts()) {
                        $my_query->the_post();
                        $image = get_field('hero_image', get_the_ID());
                        $introduction = get_field('introduction');
                        ?>
                        <article class="grid-item" data-permalink="<? the_permalink()?>">
                            <div style="background-image: url(<?php echo $image; ?>);"></div>
                            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                            <p><?php echo $introduction; ?></p>
                        </article>
                        <?
                    }
                }
                $post = $orig_post;
                wp_reset_postdata();
                wp_reset_query();
            }
            ?>
        </div>
```